# Check if a string value matches up with the content of an existing table in Oracle 11G

Tags: regex, oracle, if-statement, oracle11g

At the moment I am not working as efficient as I could be. For the problem I have I almost know certain that there is a smarter and better way to fix it.

What I am trying to do:
I got a string like this:

```
'NL 4633 4809 KTU'
```

The NL is a country code from an existing table and KTU is an university code from an existing table. I need to put this string in my function and check if the string is validated.

In my function (to validate the string) this is what I am working on. I have managed to split up the string with this:

```
 countryCode := checkISIN; -- checkISIN is the full string ('NL 4633 4809 KTU') and I am giving the NL value to this variable. countryCode is the type varchar2(50)
 countryCode := regexp_substr(countryCode, '[^ ]+', 1, 1);
```

Now that I have the country code as shown below:

```
NL
Has valid country code
```

I want to validate/check the country code for it's existence from it's own table. I tried this:

```
if countryCode in ('NL', 'FR', 'DE', 'GB', 'BE', 'US', 'CA')
 then dbms_output.put_line('Has valid country code');
 else
 dbms_output.put_line('Has invald country code. Change the country code to a valid one');
 end if;
```

This works, but it's not dynamically. If someone adds a country code then I have to change the function again.

So is there a (smart/dynamically) way to check the country codes for their existing tables?

I hope my question is not too vague

Cheers

Comment: [Reference for your solution][1],
I think same question you have repeatedly more than 2 times

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311746/check-string-for-numbers-and-characters-in-oracle-11g/30319469#30319469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Country codes table and it looks like this:

```
ID | NAME
----------
1  | NL
2  | FR
3  | BE
```

when you parse string, you can make like this :

```
 select count(1)
        into v_quan
        from CountryCodes cc
       where nvl(countryCode,'') = cc.name
if v_quan > 0 then
  dbms_output.put_line('Has valid country code');
else 
  dbms_output.put_line('Has invald country code. Change the country code to  a valid one');  
end if;
```

Comment: That does the trick. So if I understand correctly. the count(1) checks the ID number? and if the number is bigger than 0 (1, 2, 3 etc do exist) than it's valid?

Comment: count(1) was only for example, if result returns any values (0,1,2,3,..) - all will valid,   If this is confusing to you - you can use just count(*) or count(id) or etc..

Comment: Ah. I see what you you are saying. Anyway I would like to thank you for the awnser and I mark your awnser as the right given one. Cheers